# How to reset root password of a Google Compute Engine VM?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I think I have locked myself out of my VM.
I have access as a low priv user I have created but the user can't sudo.

When I do SSH->Open in browser window I get a promp asking for a password which I have never set.

Any way to reset root password from the GCP Console?

Thanks, Pavel

Answer (score 0):

To reset a root password for your GCP VM you need to grant appropriate IAM roles to your user to use sudo command. There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016795/get-root-password-for-google-cloud-engine-vm#answer-44257573). You can use the command 'sudo passwd' to change the password as suggested in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Answering yout question you could simple run `sudo` commands using a startup script as the script would run as a root user, and then add your user in sudoers with `sudo usermod -aG sudo`, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#passing-directly).

However, you could add a IAM role to your user in order to have admin access to a GCE VM, for example the `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`, [reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access#predefined-compute-engine-roles).