# What is my password when I connect via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, debian

I created a Debian VM in the Google Cloud, clicked on SSH from the GCP interface. A console shell opened, no problem, I'm logged in. Now I want to use sudo: it asks me for my current password. What is my password? Also, what is the root password?

Comment: What Google Cloud IAM Roles does your Google Cloud Console account have?

Comment: Also try `sudo bash` to launch a root shell.

Comment: Seems you have to set a password first. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35016795/5101148

Comment: Default password is insecure. That's why no password exists by defaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user account created by Google Compute Engine doesn't set a password. As an implication it is impossible to use sudo and most screen-locking apps can't unlock. 
To set password [follow steps from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#disable_screensavers_lock_screens_and_passwords):

1. Connect to the instance using SSH, as you did when you first set up the instance.
   [Here is the documentation how to connect using SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).
2. Create a password for the user:
   `sudo passwd $(whoami)`

Please note that this password will be also used on the screen lock.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.