# SSH in google cloud shell I dont understant what information it's asking for

Tags: google-compute-engine

umer_aamir11_gmail_com@experiasol-wordpress-1-vm:~$ sudo su

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

password for umer_aamir11_gmail_com:
Sorry, try again.

I dont understant what information it's asking for my passworsd is not workin on it.

Comment: [not sure what you are asking](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you are looking at? It seems you are trying to change user to root. Can you provide more information on your ask?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same command in my compute engine which is in Google Cloud Platform and logged in as root:

Last login: Tue Jun 23 XX 2020 from IP

[xxxx@vmname ~]$ sudo su

[root@vmname xxxx]#

As I understand, if you need to have root password for Google Cloud compute engine, link [1] could be helpful for you:

$ sudo passwd

Enter the new UNIX password:

Retype the new UNIX password:

passwd: password updated successfully

[1] [Get root password for Google Cloud Engine VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016795/get-root-password-for-google-cloud-engine-vm)